# Como puedo sacar el promedio de una columna? sin pandas

Tags: python, array, matriz

resulta que nos dieron una actividad que nos pide mostrar la suma de las columnas pero no puedo sacar el promedio de las mismas, eh intentado varias cosas y no puedo, les dejo el código para que vean mas o menos lo que llevo y me puedan aconsejar de como hacer la división por columnas, cabe aclarar que no nos dejan ocupar pandas, por que aún no lo implementamos

```
import random as rd, numpy as np
from numpy.core.records import array
def mostrarmatriz(matriz):
    for fila in matriz:
        print(fila)

#GENERAR LA MATRIZ CON NUMEROS REALES
matriz = []
n = int(input(" Primer Numero: "))
m = int(input( " Segundo Numero: "))
try:
    if n >= 3 and m <=6:
        if m >=3 and m <=6:
            for i in range(n):
                matriz.append([])
                for j in range(m):
                    matriz[i].append(rd.randint(0, 100))
    else:
        print('try again')
except:
    print('intentelo de nuevo')
    
mostrarmatriz(matriz)

#SUMA DE LAS COLUMNAS
filas = len(matriz)
columnas = len(matriz[0])


for i in range(filas):
    suma = sum(matriz[i])
    matriz[i].append(suma)

nueva_fila = []

for j in range(columnas):
    suma = sum(filas[j]for filas in matriz)
    nueva_fila.append(suma)
print(nueva_fila) #LA SUMA DE LAS COLUMNAS QUEDA EN LA ULTIMA FILA QUE SE MUESTRA EN PANTALLA

#PROMEDIO POR COLUMNAS
for i in range(columnas):
    p = i
    columna = [fila[i] for fila in matriz]
    print(columna)
```

Answer (score 0):

Agregue unas cosas adicionales como:

```
nueva_fila = []
nueva_fila_promedio = []
print('suma y promedio')
for j in range(columnas):
    suma = sum(filas[j]for filas in matriz)
    nueva_fila.append(suma)
    nueva_fila_promedio.append(round(suma//n))
print('la suma por cada columna es: ',nueva_fila)
print('el promedio por cada columna es: ',nueva_fila_promedio)
```

Aca vemos en la lista `nueva_fila` agregamos la suma de cada columna,
En la lista `nueva_fila_promedio` agregamos el promedio que se obtiene de la suma entre la cantidad de filas que esta dada por `n` cuando ingresas el valor.
Por ultimo lo imprimimos y como resultado me da:

```
 Primer Numero: 4
 Segundo Numero: 5
matriz original
[15, 95, 12, 53, 59]
[89, 88, 25, 17, 14]
[6, 7, 44, 80, 94]
[90, 88, 44, 27, 6]
suma y promedio
la suma por cada columna es:  [200, 278, 125, 177, 173]
el promedio por cada columna es:  [50, 69, 31, 44, 43]
```

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar **no necesitas pandas!**, pandas es utilizado para trabajar con DataFrames, archivos Excel o cualquier archivo que contenga varios datos o información, y en tu caso, si decides usar pandas solo harías cosas en vano.

Al ya tener la suma de las columnas, lo único que debes de hacer es iterar en ellas y dividir según el número de filas que haya, lo que vendría a ser tu variable  `n` en donde pides los datos al principio.

```py
#PROMEDIO POR COLUMNAS
prom = [round(p/n,3) for p in nueva_fila] #nueva fila contiene la suma de las columnas
print(f"Promedio de columnas: {prom}")
```

Utilizo una comprensión de lista por que es un proceso sencillo, lo que hace es iterara en `nueva_fila` creando una variable `p` y a esta variable la divide entre el valor de `n` y utilizamos `round()` para redondear a 3 decimales en caso el numero sea largo y el resultado es añadido a la lista `prom` para luego ser impresa.